# CSS/JQuery - moving speech bubbles point to a specific dot

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set up the following fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6kp6d83/)
As you can see, I have two dots on the page and a speech bubble.  These dots are buttons, and when clicked, the speech bubble should be associated with it.

At the moment, I have the speech bubble in the container for the first dot

```
<div id="button-one-container">
    <button id="1" class="btn active"></button>
    <div id="button-one-bubble">
        <article class="popup">
            <div class="image">
            </div>
            <div class="bubble">
                <h1>2000</h1>
                <h2>Some Text</h2>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure if this should be in a more generic position?  Ideally, I need to keep the speech bubble where it is (on the page).  As such, when a dot is clicked, I need to somehow make the arrow part of the speech bubble point to the dot (it will have to grow and move possibly).

Would something like this be possible?  If so, how would I go about achieving this?  So I am after the single speech bubble which stays where it is, but the arrow part of the speech bubble to link to the dot when clicked.

Thanks

Comment: It will not be a simple task to move the arrow of the speech bubble dynamically. If possible it would be *a lot* easier to move the whole bubble so that the arrow points to the required dot.